# How to position text at end of previous block of text?

Tags: html, css

We are using a CMS which limits my ability to edit the HTML.  I have a paragraph of text, followed by a link:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
>   sed do eiusmodtempor incididunt ut labore.
>
> *Click here*

Our designer would prefer to have the "Click here" link appear directly at the end of the paragraph of text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
>   sed do eiusmodtempor incididunt ut labore.  *Click here*

Is it possible to position the link with CSS such that it always appears at the end of the preceding paragraph?  Here is the HTML produced by our CMS:

```
<div class="item summary">
    <div class="content">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum...
        </p>
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="item link">
    <div class="content">
        <a href="http://www.example.com">Click here</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this to work, basically all your elements (div, p, a) need to be inline or inline-block elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/mkeyh93f/

```
div.item{
    display: inline;
}

div.item p, div.item div, div.item a{
    display: inline;
}
```

Just make sure you also don't have any default padding and margins on your elements. I would also suggest wrapping it all up in a div or article container with display: block;

Comment: Thanks.  This *would* work, but our CMS uses (and our consultants created) such a convoluted mess of nested and shared classes, so I can't get it work without breaking a bunch of other stuff.  But thank you for your quick response!

Comment: As a final update, I did manage to make this work.  Our stuff is still convoluted, but your solution worked.  Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set

```
float: right;
```

in your item link. Or use a table layout.

Tip: Set no blanks in your css class names ("itemLink").

Answer (score 0):

If possible change the div to span or in the css,
add

```
.item, .item.content, .item.content p,
.item.summary .item.link {display: inline;}
.item.summary item.link .content {display: inline;}
```

This would change the behavior of the div element.m which is sort of anti-intuitive. DIVs are semantically divisions and so, making a div act like a span is not recommended. Use it only as a last resort

Answer (score 0):

There is one way of doing it using jquery i hope this will some wat help you since we cannot adjust using css. We can use it via jquery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".link").each(function(){
       var a=$(this).children(".content").html();
$(this).siblings(".summary").children(".content").children("p").append(a);
    });
    $(".item.link").remove();
});
</script>
```

And No changes in html content try this and let me know if this function works or not

Answer (score -1):

```
div p{
float: Right;
}

or

div p{
Display: inline;
}
```

these both worked for me